# C++ Add number to Array Object?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I am implementing a communication interface for the operating system Rodos from C++ to Java.
My C++ is a little bit "rusty" and I've never seen this operation before: `header+0` for an array!

rodos/api/gateway/networkmessage.h:

```
class NetworkMessage {
    static const int HEADER_SIZE = 26;
    uint8_t header [HEADER_SIZE];
public:
    inline void    put_checkSum(uint16_t x)          {int16_tToBigEndian(header+0, x); }
    inline void    put_senderNode(int32_t x)         {int32_tToBigEndian(header+2, x); }
```

rodos/support_libs/stream-bytesex.cpp:

```
void int16_tToBigEndian(void* buff, uint16_t value) {
    uint8_t* byteStream = (uint8_t*)buff;
    if (byteStream == 0) return;
    byteStream[0] = (uint8_t) ((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byteStream[1] = (uint8_t) ((value >> 0) & 0xFF);
}
```

How do I have to implement this addition of an integer-array and an integer in Java?

Comment: It is equivalent to `&header[0]` and `&header[2]`, i.e. it gives you a pointer to an element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are mostly syntactic sugar over typed pointers. For `T foo[...]` declaration, an expression `foo + 2` means *pointer* to the 3rd element of array `foo`.

Comment: Pedantry:  In C++ arrays only *appear* to be syntactic sugar over pointers because an array will decompose in to a pointer at the drop of a hat.  That doesn't matter much in the context of this answer, however.